# Dispose inner subscription of merge

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

!!warning: Rx newbie!!

We have multiple price feeds. The requirement is to subscribe to all these feeds and only output the latest tick every 1 sec(throttle)

```
 public static class FeedHandler
{
        private static IObservable<PriceTick> _combinedPriceFeed = null;

          private static double _throttleFrequency = 1000;

        public static void AddToCombinedFeed(IObservable<PriceTick> feed)
        {
            _combinedPriceFeed = _combinedPriceFeed != null ? _combinedPriceFeed.Merge(feed) : feed;
            AddFeed(_combinedPriceFeed);
        }

              private static IDisposable _subscriber;

        private static void AddFeed(IObservable<PriceTick> feed)
        {
            _subscriber?.Dispose();
            _subscriber = feed.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_throttleFrequency)).Subscribe(buffer => buffer.GroupBy(x => x.InstrumentId, (key, result) => result.First()).ToObservable().Subscribe(NotifyClient));
        }

         public static void NotifyClient(PriceTick tick)
        {
        //Do some action
        }

}
```

The code have multiple issues. If I call AddToCombinedFeed with the same feed multiple times, the streams will get duplicated to start with. Eg. below

```
IObservable<PriceTick> feed1;

FeedHandler.AddToCombinedFeed(feed1);//1 stream
FeedHandler.AddToCombinedFeed(feed1);//2 streams(even though the groupby and first() functions will prevent this effect to propagate further
```

This brings me to the question. If I want to remove one price stream from the merged stream, how can I do that?

Comment: You should never ever have an inner subscription in the first place.

Comment: What is the reasoning of avoiding inner subscription?

Comment: Because you can end up with race conditions and it's difficult to properly dispose of the inner subscription. The observable pipeline has been designed to clean up after itself so you should always write a single query rather than multiple inner ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update - New Solution**

With [Dynamic-Data](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData) (MIT-License) from RolandPheasant with Nuget.

1. Use a SourceList instead of a List
2. Use the MergeMany operator

Code:

```
public class FeedHandler
{
    private readonly IDisposable _subscriber;
    private readonly SourceList<IObservable<PriceTick>> _feeds = new SourceList<IObservable<PriceTick>>();
    private readonly double _throttleFrequency = 1000;

    public FeedHandler()
    {
        var combinedPriceFeed = _feeds.Connect().MergeMany(x => x).Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_throttleFrequency)).SelectMany(buffer => buffer.GroupBy(x => x.InstrumentId, (key, result) => result.First()));
        _subscriber = combinedPriceFeed.Subscribe(NotifyClient);
    }

    public void AddFeed(IObservable<PriceTick> feed) => _feeds.Add(feed);

    public void NotifyClient(PriceTick tick)
    {
        //Do some action
    }
}
```

**Old Solution**

1. Eradicate the need to resubscribe by applying Switch() technique.
   Your _combinedPriceFeed just switches to the next observable that
   will be supplied by _combinePriceFeedChange.

   2. Keep a list to manage your multiple feeds. Create the new observable whenever the list changes and provide it via _combinePriceFeedChange.
   3. You should get the logic of an corresponding remove method.

Code:

```
public class FeedHandler
{
    private readonly IDisposable _subscriber;
    private readonly IObservable<PriceTick> _combinedPriceFeed;
    private readonly List<IObservable<PriceTick>> _feeds = new List<IObservable<PriceTick>>();
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<IObservable<PriceTick>> _combinedPriceFeedChange = new BehaviorSubject<IObservable<PriceTick>>(Observable.Never<PriceTick>());
    private readonly double _throttleFrequency = 1000;

    public FeedHandler()
    {
        _combinedPriceFeed = _combinedPriceFeedChange.Switch().Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_throttleFrequency)).SelectMany(buffer => buffer.GroupBy(x => x.InstrumentId, (key, result) => result.First()));
        _subscriber = _combinedPriceFeed.Subscribe(NotifyClient);
    }

    public void AddFeed(IObservable<PriceTick> feed)
    {
        _feeds.Add(feed);
        _combinedPriceFeedChange.OnNext(_feeds.Merge());
    }


    public void NotifyClient(PriceTick tick)
    {
        //Do some action
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any practical advantage to prefer switch over re-subscription? Isn't switch doing the same thing behind the scenes?

Comment: That a resubscription is not needed is exactly the advantage. Its a declarative way to handle the disposal/resubscription. The _combinedPriceFeed-Observable is always valid. In my code most of the time the IObservable is a public property or it is generated by a method and I don't want to break existing subscriptions from the providing side other than Error/Completion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code you need:

```
private static SerialDisposable _subscriber = new SerialDisposable();

private static void AddFeed(IObservable<PriceTick> feed)
{
    _subscriber.Disposable =
        feed
            .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_throttleFrequency))
            .SelectMany(buffer =>
                buffer
                    .GroupBy(x => x.InstrumentId, (key, result) => result.First()))
            .Subscribe(NotifyClient);
}
```